# How to resize my widgets by ratio in android

Tags: java, android

I want to resize my widgets in the layout by ratio, but I can't.

At time I resizing ViewPager or com.daimajia.slider.SliderLayout by ratio and Measure, but childs of ViewPager or com.daimajia.slider.SliderLayout lose their height.

I create a custom widget for this work.
Code example for ImageView:

```
package ...;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class SquareImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    int w = 0, h = 0;
    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        if (getMeasuredWidth() == 0 || getMeasuredHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            w = getMeasuredWidth();
            h = getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        return;
    }
    else {
        w = getWidth();
        h = getHeight();
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, w);
    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, rect, rect, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;

    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor),
                (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sbmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final String color = "#BAB399";
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
}
```

My Codes not worked for this widgets:
ViewPager, com.daimajia.slider.SliderLayout.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
//------------> ***** Answer - Go Down ***** <------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
//------------> ***** Answer - Go Down ***** <------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
//------------> ***** Answer - Go Down ***** <------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------
```

I found the answer my question.

```
public class ViewPagerByRatioSize extends ViewPager {

Integer layout_ratioX = 0, layout_ratioY = 0;

public ViewPagerByRatioSize(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ViewPagerByRatioSize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ViewPagerByRatioSize, 0, 0);
    try {
        layout_ratioX = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.ViewPagerByRatioSize_layout_ratioXViewPager, 0);
        layout_ratioY = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.ViewPagerByRatioSize_layout_ratioYViewPager, 0);
    }
    finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    super.setMeasuredDimension(width, width / layout_ratioX * layout_ratioY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width / layout_ratioX * layout_ratioY, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}
}
```

This code worked for me, but I change codes because my application can't get values from xml codes.

This new codes:

```
public class ViewPagerByRatioSize extends ViewPager {

public ViewPagerByRatioSize(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ViewPagerByRatioSize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    super.setMeasuredDimension(width, width / 3 * 2);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width / 3 * 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}
}
```

Successful for ever :)

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to the android:layout_weight attribute from a LinearLayout?

Comment: @keara approximately

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what behavior you want and exactly what's going wrong?

Comment: @keara  At time I using this class for extends ViewPager or ..., height of childs of their classes will be 0, then:  I can't see childs of their element because heights of childs of my custom widgets be 0

Comment: I find answer my question, but thanks @Keara for try to help me. I put answer under the question.